# Best Way To Remove Fajita Contents From Marinade

Tags: marinade, mexican-cuisine

Usually when I marinade something it's just a single piece of meat.  I can just pull it out and discard the rest of the marinade.  However, when I have strips of chicken and vegetables all marinating in a single bag what's the best way to remove the contents?  Should I just strain the bag  over the sink? Or should I just reach in with tongs and pull everything out?

I guess my problem with both solutions is losing too much marinade from straining (don't want to lose more flavor than I have to) or pulling in too much liquid from using tongs (I don't want my tortillas to get soggy)

Any advice would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colander over a bowl. That saves the marinade, so you can use as much as you want. Be sure you completely cook all of the marinade that you use, and discard the rest. It is not safe to reuse it.

Comment: Okay, so when you say use as much as I want you mean incase the fajitas are not as flavored as I want I can add some more marinade in until I get the desired taste?  Then discard after done cooking?

Comment: @CuriousCooker Yes, but if you do it that way, bring the reserved marinade to a rolling boil. Still discard any leftover marinade, but you can use as much as you want while you are cooking the meal. You can also reduce/thicken the marinade that way. NICE!